# makefile with 2 source directories make include guard fail

Tags: c, makefile, include-guards

I have a project with sources in 2 locations. 
When the project links, it complains that a function is double-defined (it's not):

```
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src src/Meter.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Meter.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src src/PaymentHandler.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/PaymentHandler.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src src/PaymentHandlerDaemon.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/PaymentHandlerDaemon.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src src/PrintSocketReceiver.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/PrintSocketReceiver.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src src/SerialPrinter.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/SerialPrinter.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src ../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/CheckSum.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src ../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/Config.o
cc build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Meter.o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/PaymentHandler.o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/PaymentHandlerDaemon.o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/PrintSocketReceiver.o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/SerialPrinter.o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/CheckSum.o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/Config.o -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/../PaymentHandlerDaemon -lrt -lpthread -lconfig -lm -L../../libSOS/trunk/build/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSOS  -L../lib/ABCUtilLib/build/x86_64-linux-gnu -lABCUtil -L../lib/ABCUtilSO/build/x86_64-linux-gnu   -lABCMain
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/Config.o: In function `CheckSum_Buffer':
/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c:34: multiple definition of `CheckSum_Buffer'
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/CheckSum.o:/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c:34: first defined here
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/Config.o: In function `CheckSum_Stream':
/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c:54: multiple definition of `CheckSum_Stream'
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/CheckSum.o:/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c:54: first defined here
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/Config.o: In function `pppfcs16':
/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c:125: multiple definition of `pppfcs16'
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/CheckSum.o:/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c:125: first defined here
build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Meter.o: In function `Meter_MessagePumpProc':
/home/builder/projects/Applications/PaymentHandlerDaemon/trunk/src/Meter.c:365: undefined reference to `Config_GetHardwareInfo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/../PaymentHandlerDaemon] Error 1
```

I think it is because the makefile has 2 different recipes to compile for each directory and they don't share the pre-compile definitions.

is there a better way of making a project with 2 source directories? Should I just add the few sources in the different directory to a mini-library and then add that?

Makefile:

```
CC ?= gcc
ARCH = $(shell $(CC) -dumpmachine)

# compile and link flags
CC_FLAGS ?= -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__

CC_INCLUDE = -I../../libSOS/trunk/include
CC_INCLUDE += -I. -I../../include
CC_INCLUDE += -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src
CC_INCLUDE += -I../../Bla/trunk/src

# Libraries
LIBS := -lrt -lpthread -lconfig -lm
LIBS += -L../../libSOS/trunk/build/$(ARCH) -lSOS 
LIBS += -L../lib/ABCUtilLib/build/$(ARCH) -lABCUtil
LIBS += -L../lib/ABCUtilSO/build/$(ARCH)    -lABCMain


OUT1_DIR = build/$(ARCH)/obj
OUT2_DIR = build/$(ARCH)/obj/Bla

# result
EXEC = ${OUT1_DIR}/../PaymentHandlerDaemon

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# main sources (1)
SRC1_DIR = src
#all the sources in the srec directory will be included
SOURCES1 = $(wildcard ${SRC1_DIR}/*.c)
# deduce the object list from the source list
_OBJECTS1 = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES1) )
# the replace the source directory wioth the output directory
OBJECTS1 = $(patsubst ${SRC1_DIR}%,${OUT1_DIR}%,$(_OBJECTS1) )

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# extra sources (2)
SRC2_DIR = ../../Bla/trunk/src
#SRC2_LIST = Meter.c
SRC2_LIST = CheckSum.c Config.c
#all the sources in the srec directory will be included
#SOURCES2 = $(pathsubs %,$(SRC2_DIR)/%,$(SRC2_LIST))
SOURCES2 =  $(patsubst %.c,${SRC2_DIR}/%.c,$(SRC2_LIST))
# deduce the object list from the source list
_OBJECTS2 = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES2) )
# the replace the source directory wioth the output directory
OBJECTS2 = $(patsubst ${SRC2_DIR}%,${OUT2_DIR}%,$(_OBJECTS2) )

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# build receipes

all: $(EXEC)
# Main target
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS1) $(OBJECTS2)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS1) $(OBJECTS2) -o $@ $(LIBS)


# To obtain object files
${OUT1_DIR}%.o:${SRC1_DIR}%.c 
    @mkdir -p $(OUT1_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_INCLUDE) $< -o $@

# # To obtain object files
 ${OUT2_DIR}%.o:${SOURCES2}
    @mkdir -p $(OUT2_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_INCLUDE) $< -o $@


# To remove generated files
clean:
    rm -fr build/$(ARCH)


# debug.. for example use as    make -print-SRC_DIR
print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People build a projects from multiple directories all the time. Each case requires a different approach.

What you posted should work. A multiple definition is most likely *not* because of the `Makefile`. I would look at the error more closely. The `toolchain` is telling you where it found the two definitions.

Makefile:

```
CC ?= gcc
# compile and link flags
CC_FLAGS ?= -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og 

CC_INCLUDE += -I../../AnotherProject/src

# Libraries
LIBS := -lrt -lpthread -lconfig -lm

OUT1_DIR = build/obj
OUT2_DIR = build/obj/extra2

# result
EXEC = build/MyProgram

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# main sources (1) (everything in src directory)
SRC1_DIR = src
SOURCES1 = $(wildcard ${SRC1_DIR}/*.c)
# deduce the object list from the source list
_OBJECTS1 = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES1) )
# the replace the source directory wioth the output directory
OBJECTS1 = $(patsubst ${SRC1_DIR}%,${OUT1_DIR}%,$(_OBJECTS1) )

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# extra sources (just cherry pick what i need to reuse)
SRC2_DIR = ../../AnotherProject/src
SRC2_LIST = CheckSum.c Config.c
#all the sources in the srec directory will be included
SOURCES2 =  $(patsubst %.c,${SRC2_DIR}/%.c,$(SRC2_LIST))
# deduce the object list from the source list
_OBJECTS2 = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES2) )
# the replace the source directory wioth the output directory
OBJECTS2 = $(patsubst ${SRC2_DIR}%,${OUT2_DIR}%,$(_OBJECTS2) )

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# build receipes

all: debug $(EXEC)

debug: FORCE
    echo "1====" $(OBJECTS1)
    echo "2====" $(OBJECTS2)

FORCE:

# Main target
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS1) $(OBJECTS2)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS1) $(OBJECTS2) -o $@ $(LIBS)


# To obtain object files
${OUT1_DIR}/%.o:${SRC1_DIR}/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(OUT1_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_INCLUDE) $< -o $@

# To obtain the extra object files
${OUT2_DIR}/%.o:${SRC2_DIR}/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(OUT2_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

**EDIT**

Here is your problem.

```
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src ../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/CheckSum.o
cc -c -c -w -fPIC -g3 -Og -D__EMULATE_SOS__ -I../../libSOS/trunk/include -I. -I../../include -I../lib/ABCUtilSO/src -I../../Bla/trunk/src ../../Bla/trunk/src/CheckSum.c -o build/x86_64-linux-gnu/obj/Bla/Config.o
```

You see that it is building both `CheckSum.o` and `Config.o` from the same source file `CheckSum.c`. Hence the multiple definitions at link time. This is the consequence of the bad pattern rule you had.

```
${OUT2_DIR}%.o:${SOURCES2}
```

Comment: thanks ziffusion. i just updated the question with the actual output of the error.

Comment: Can you post the entire build output? Also, is the Makefile correct? I see a couple of weird things. 1. `${OUT1_DIR}%.o:${SRC1_DIR}%.c ${SOURCES2}` seems odd. 2. `${OUT2_DIR}%.o:${SOURCES2}` does not seem properly indented.

Comment: I unindented the `${OUT2_DIR}%.o:${SOURCES2}` line — it was otherwise a weird one.  It looks to me as though every object file depends on every source file, so if a source file changes, all the object files in that directory will be recompiled.  I doubt if that's what's wanted.

Comment: I've added a `Makefile` to the answer that you can try. Look at what `$(OBJECTS1)` and `$(OBJECTS2)` are. There are other changes as well. Make sure you replace reading spaces with tabs.

Comment: i had simplified the makefile and output to illustrate the problem. i have updated the question to the full makefile and full error list. just ignore the libraries because before i made the change to add some extra source from the other directory , this was working,

Comment: perhaps i just need to put those few extra files from the other directory in a library and link them together ?

Comment: i finally tweaked to what you were saying.. change ${OUT2_DIR}%.o:${SOURCES2}  to ${OUT2_DIR}%.o:${SRC2_DIR}/%.c and it works now..  I was thinking that it would compile everything in SRC2_DIR but it only gets called for the files i need. thank you !!!!

Comment: I added an explanation for why you were seeing a multiple definition.